# Compare different column values together between two files and if match print different column value

Tags: awk, csv-simple

File1 has data as below , is the field separator

```
1,T_EXIT,9053.0,10325.0,, ,  
2,V_TURN,120.0,11334.0,,GOAL,RECK
3,Q_ENTRY,122.0,190.0,, ,
4,Q_ENTRY_RUN,130.0,569.0,, ,
```

File2 has data

```
SYNC CLK
T_EXIT OPEN 
Q_ENTRY CLOSE ALLOW
CORE_T MODE
```

I want to compare column1 of file2 with column2 of file1 and if EXCAT MATCH is there I want to copy column2 from file2 in column6 and column3 from file2 in column7 in file1

I want output as:

```
1,T_EXIT,9053.0,10325.0,,OPEN,
2,V_TURN,120.0,11334.0,,GOAL,RECK 
3,Q_ENTRY,122.0,190.0,,CLOSE,ALLOW
4,Q_ENTRY_RUN,130.0,569.0,, ,
```

I tried below code, but I could not get how to save two column values column1 and column2 together from file2.

```
awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;B[$1]=$3;next} ($1 in A) {$6=A[$1]; $7=B[$1]}1' file2 FS=, OFS=, file1 > test
```

Comment: your own approach is OK, you were just checking on wrong column# of file1; you should do `awk 'NR==FNR{A[$1]=$2;B[$1]=$3;next} ($2 in A) {$6=A[$2]; $7=B[$2]}1' file2 FS=, OFS=, file1`; I have also showed you a similar approach below.

Comment: I am not able to get data in column7. with ```$7=B[$2]```

Comment: but you are getting! run it to see. but you are only geting column7 for the 3rd line comparison of the file2's column1 with column2 of file1 and you don't get for others becasuse you really don't have data for them from the file2! ***Additionally my answer is also updated according to your revised output.***

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{ data[$1]=$2 OFS $3; next }
  ($2 in data){ sub(/[^,]*,[^,]*$/, ""); $0=$0 data[$2] }1' OFS=, file2 FS=, file1

1,T_EXIT,9053.0,10325.0,,OPEN,
2,V_TURN,120.0,11334.0,,GOAL,RECK
3,Q_ENTRY,122.0,190.0,,CLOSE,ALLOW
4,Q_ENTRY_RUN,130.0,569.0,, ,
```

With `sub(/[^,]*,[^,]*$/, "")`, we are stripping off the last two fields (which for your input those are columns 6&7) when we found that column2 of file1 match with the column1 of file2 by looking that keys collected in the *data* associated array previously, then append the value of that key from file2 with `$0= $0 data[$2]`.